# Callback Function .html(), and .val() together possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

back again! been a while.
So this is my question.

I have a datatable set up that gets the information from the database and shows this in a modal (bootstrap4).
That works fine by the way, but now I wan't to add a dropdown option.
This dropdown needs to have information that is stored in the database (just one table with all the rows).

```
            success:function(data){
            $('#Modal').modal('show');
            $('#Id').val(data.id);
            $('.number').html("<select><option>".val(data.number)"</option></select>");
            $('#skills').val(data.skills);  
            $('.modal-title').html("<i class='edit'></i> Edit ");
            $('#action').val('Data');
            $('#save').val('Save');
        }
```

as you can see I tried to do this little trick but sadly it didn't take so I was wondering if something like this is even possible?

Thanks so much for the help/info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your modal already contains a `select` box in a `.number` div with several options in it then the following would add the extra option into it, generated from the `data` object:

```
$('.number select').append(`<option value="${data.number}">${data.number}"</option>`);
```